# Moving Redirect/Rewrite rules from IIRF Filter to htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm moving a PHP site from a locally hosted IIS 6 server to Pagoda Box.  This site had previously been coded in Coldfusion and only recently, I re-coded it in PHP.  For Google Analytics, I have made all outward facing links extension-less, while serving up the correspodnig .php file:

```
<a href="link">My Link</a>
```

REQUEST:

```
/link
```

BROWSER BAR:

```
 http://www.example.com/link
```

RESPONSE:

```
/link.php
```

I had previously been using the Ionic Shade IIRF Re-write filter and now obviously will use htaccess.  My previous IIRF rules looked like this:

```
RedirectRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)\.cfm((\?.*)|())$   /$1$2 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)((\?.*)|())$   /$1.php$2
```

So, in my htaccess file, I've tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.pagodabox\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)((\?.*)|())$ $1.php$2 [R=301,L]
```

My extension-less links serve-up the correct .php file with any query string.  However, you see the .php extension in the browser bar.  How do I need to modify my htaccess file so it functions like my previous IIRF rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the [`R=301`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag.

This flag causes the web server to send a `Location` response to the browser and forces the browser to request the new URL.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!  I've been working all week on configuring  this new cloud server, so it's easy to over look the small details.